# Rotate / Bounce Image from the Central Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created the following on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/silvawebdesigns2020/pen/xxGxKEp)

**HTML**

```
  <div class="demo-container clocks active bounce">
      <section class="seconds-container">
        <section class="seconds"></section>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.demo-container.clocks {
  background: #3cd19e;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 548px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hours-container {
  animation: rotate 43200s infinite linear;
}

.linear {
  .minutes-container {
    animation: rotate 3600s infinite linear;
  }
  .seconds-container {
    animation: rotate 60s infinite linear;
  }
}

.steps {
  .minutes-container {
    animation: rotate 3600s infinite steps(60);
  }
  .seconds-container {
    animation: rotate 60s infinite steps(60);
  }
}

.local.steps {
  .minutes-container {
    animation: none;
  }
}

.bounce {
  .minutes-container {
    transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(.4,2.08,.55,.44);
  }
  .seconds-container {
    transition: transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(.4,2.08,.55,.44);
  }
}

.seconds {
  background: url(https://svgur.com/i/Hmu.svg);
  width: 500px;
  height: 548px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  z-index: 8;
  animation: rotate 60s infinite steps(60);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    /*transform: rotateZ(360deg);*/
  }
}


.seconds-container {
  transition: transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(.4,2.08,.55,.44);
}
```

**JS**

```
/*
 *  Main function to set the clock times
 */
(function() {
  // Start the seconds container moving
  moveSecondHands();
})();

/*
 * Move the second containers
 */
function moveSecondHands() {
  var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.bounce .seconds-container');
  setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
      if (containers[i].angle === undefined) {
        containers[i].angle = 6;
      } else {
        containers[i].angle += 6;
      }
      containers[i].style.webkitTransform = 'rotateZ('+ containers[i].angle +'deg)';
      containers[i].style.transform = 'rotateZ('+ containers[i].angle +'deg)';
    }
  }, 1000);
  for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    // Add in a little delay to make them feel more natural
    var randomOffset = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
    containers[i].style.transitionDelay = '0.0'+ randomOffset +'s';
  }
}
```

I basically want the image to rotate 360 and have that bounce effect as well. Just can't figure out how to keep the image in the same position so the rotation occurs from the central point (the image stays in the same location)

Any ideas?

---

So basically I need to combine `animation: rotate 60s infinite steps(60);` with the bounce effect shown in the codepen.

Comment: simply remove position:absolute from the inner element

Comment: Oh my days haha, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```css
.seconds {
    background: url(https://svgur.com/i/Hmu.svg);
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1097px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: 50%;
    z-index: 8;
    animation: rotate 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    75% {
        transform: scale(0.98);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(0.95);
    }
    25% {
        transform: scale(0.98);
    }`enter code here`
    to {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25360413)